# How to save or storing the SKPayment transaction?

Tags: ios, transactions, save, nsuserdefaults, storekit

I would like to store the SKPayment transaction in the user defaults or on the device, and I also would like to store the transaction data on my server at a later date (not done yet) so that a user can restore a subscription if required/necessary/possible.

The problem I am having is that I try to save to user defaults but it keeps telling me:

> *** -[NSUserDefaults setObject:forKey:]: Attempt to insert non-property value '{
>       transaction = ""; }' of class '__NSCFDictionary'.

The code I use is:

```
 // Save
    NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    [dict setObject:transaction forKey:@"transaction"];    
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:dict forKey:@"TransactionReceipt"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

    // Read    
    NSMutableDictionary *savedDict =  [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"MyTransactionReceipt"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

    NSLog(@"Saved stored transaction = %@", savedDict);
```

I also tried saving the Transaction object itself rather than store it in a dictionary, but this gives always gives an error, where it complains of

> "Attempt to insert non-insert property value ..."

I also tried using NSKeyedArchiver, but I wasn't sure how to code it to handle the reading and writing of a SKPaymentTransaction.

Any help on this would be most appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've resolved the problem by storing the transaction data in a plist inside the documents directory.

This was much easier and much more reliable for my requirements.

Basic code follows for those wishing to do the same.

```
// WRITING        
// Save to documents directory
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *receiptStorageFile = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"receipts.plist"];

NSLog(@"Reciept Storage File = %@", receiptStorageFile);

NSMutableArray *receiptStorage = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:receiptStorageFile];
if(!receiptStorage) {
    receiptStorage = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}

NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[dict setObject:transaction.transactionIdentifier forKey:@"transactionIdentifier"];
[dict setObject:transaction.transactionDate forKey:@"transactionDate"];
[dict setObject:transaction.transactionReceipt forKey:@"transactionReceipt"];

// Write
[receiptStorage addObject:dict];
[receiptStorage writeToFile:receiptStorageFile atomically:YES];
[receiptStorage release];


// READING

// Get app documents directory
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);            
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];            
NSLog(@"DocumentsDirectory = %@", documentsDirectory);

// Load from documents directory            
NSArray *receipts = [[[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"receipts.plist"]] autorelease];
// Found a receipt on disk
if ([receipts count]>0) {
    // Do something, read the dictionary, etc.
} // end if
```